# upload image from ios app to notes & attachment

Tags: apex, upload, ios

I would like to upload image to notes & attachement filed of a custom object via ios app.

Tried to upload via apex class but it always upload it to the commom "document folder".

struggling for long time to find a solution.Any help would be great :(

Comment: You will need to insert an Attachment object whose ParentId field is set to the ID of the custom object.

Comment: any sample code would be helpful. Thanks in advance.